# Generate Universal Unique Identifier

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista, uuid

Is it possible to generate a Universal Unique Identifier or Global Unique Identifier (UUID or GUID) in a Windows shell script? Linux / Unix / Mac OS X have the bin utility `uuidgen` and I'm curious if Windows has an equivalent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an eponymous Windows port of `uuidgen` available with Visual Studio.

Documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't have a copy of Visual Studio. Do you know if a universal binary is available for this? Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio Express Edition is free and can be downloaded from Microsoft. You could then pull out the specific files you need.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions (I don't use Windows as my main OS). Will I be able to package the identifier such that users downloading my script won't require installation of Visual Studio? If not it isn't really an option. Thanks!

Comment: s/eponymous/homonymous/ ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419) it's very easy:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Jeff> $guid = [guid]::NewGuid()
PS C:\Users\Jeff> $guid

Guid
----
fe2858b1-2b70-4b2b-994d-3ff22f85244e
```